# Draggable div clone using jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I have here an big problem for me, becouse i'm beginer to this.

I using jquery ui to drag and drop div but I need it to clone div when I start dragging.

I try with this code but something is wrong with that:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(evt) {
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).resizable();
  $( ".draggable" ).draggable({revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone', snap: "#drop_here td", opacity: 0.7});
    $( "#drop_here td" ).droppable({
      accept: '.draggable',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });    });
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/erofot/17

Doeas anybody know why this code not working?

Comment: What is happening? Is the div dragging at all? Is it dragging but not cloning? Give more details please. "Something is wrong" is impossible to troubleshoot :)

Comment: yes dragging but not cloning

Comment: Here you can see want I want to do: http://jsbin.com/erofot/17, so div must be draggable into table and resizable and offcource to not change table row height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a clone of the object being dragged, correct?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(evt) {
  $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).resizable();
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ helper: 'clone', snap: "#drop_here td", opacity: 0.7});
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        start: function() {
            var drgClone = $(this).clone(true);
        }
    })
    $( "#drop_here td" ).droppable({
      accept: '.draggable',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: not work well. 1.table change height on dragging, 2. div is not resizable after dragging, 3. div won't stay at position as I want so, not left:0px ...

Comment: Here you can see want I want to do: http://jsbin.com/erofot/17, so div must be draggable into table and resizable and offcource to not change table row height

Comment: So I need all to work just like here: http://jsbin.com/erofot/17 but with cloning

Comment: Why don't you just view and attempt to replicate the JavaScript that they're using on that demo site?

Comment: this is my code, I use only this example drom jquery tutorials but there is no something like I need

Comment: I also try to do something like: ui.helper.draggable(); but don't work

Comment: is there any way to do that, please help me!

Comment: If you really want some help, I suggest you post all of your code on http://www.jsfiddle.com so we can see exactly what is happening and what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The helper: 'clone' option for a draggable only creates a clone of the div while dragging.

Try appending a clone during the drop event of the droppable widget. (Note: I also removed the revert option from the draggable as it's not needed)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(evt) {
  $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).resizable();
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ helper: 'clone', snap: "#drop_here td", opacity: 0.7});
    $( "#drop_here td" ).droppable({
      accept: '.draggable',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: yes but after dragging, the div position is in left:0px and dont stay like I want also the resizable dont work after dragging

Comment: Here you can see want I want to do: http://jsbin.com/erofot/17, so div must be draggable into table and resizable and offcource to not change table row height, so I need to work like this but with cloning, just that. How to do that?

Comment: After you clone the item into the droppable area, you would need to bind the cloned object up as a new draggable and resizable.

Comment: yes, to be new object an also to stay at position as a draged from sidebar so ect. left:55px or some value...

Comment: so please show on this example hoe this would be. thanks very much

Comment: I also try to do something like: ui.helper.draggable(); but don't work, please help me to finish that